# "Unknown column 'column_name' in 'table_name'" error while running django migrate command to rename a field

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am trying to connect an already existing database to django. I was able to make the models using inspectDb command. I have made the initial migrations as well. The problem has started occurring when I am trying to rename a field. It shows the error "Unknown column 'column_name' in 'table_name'", even when the column in the given table exists.
I want to rename my fields and have those changes reflected in my database.

Model I got from inspect db

```
class ManufacturerModel(models.Model):
    auto_manufacturer_model_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturer_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer_year_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'manufacturer_model'
```

Changed I want to be reflected in databse:

```
class ManufacturerModel(models.Model):
    auto_manufacturer_model_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    manufacturr_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    manufacturer_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'manufacturer_model'
```

ERROR: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'manufacturer_id ' in 'manufacturer_model'")

I want the database changes to be reflected properly after i run the migrate command without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `python manage.py makemigrations` and then run `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: The error is occurring after the `python manage.py migrate` command. I have already run the `makemigrations` command, that didn't give any errors

Answer (score 0):

After modify your model, you must apply migrations by running `python manage.py makemigrations`
before running the `python manage.py migrate` command line.

Comment: The error is occurring after the `python manage.py migrate` command. I have already run the `makemigrations` command, that didn't give any errors

Comment: Make sure you run again the `python manage.py makemigrations` each time you modify your models.py file. I notice also in your modifications you rename the `manufacturer_id` to `manufacturr_id`. Make sure it's the name you use in your code.